# Environment variables not available in Elastic Beanstalk Procfile

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

I'm attempting to configure my elastic beanstalk java application using environment variables via the Procfile like so:

```
web: ./bin/myservice -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

The `PORT` environment variable is set via the AWS ui in the "Software Configuration" screen of my beanstalk environment.

However, the logs are indicating that `$PORT` is not being interpolated:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.whatever.services.myservice.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$PORT"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
```

What is the correct way to pass options to my application?

**Edit 1:** This seems to be an issue related to the sbt native packager plugin which I use to create a distributable zip archive of the project. The bin/myservice file it generates is interpreting $PORT literally and passing that to the application.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, use a variable in my Procfile. Did you ever have any luck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `-Dhttp.port=$PORT` from `Procfile`.

In the ui in "Software Configuration" try setting the variable `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Dhttp.port=9000` (replace 9000 with whatever port your nginx proxy is using -- 5000 is the default I believe).

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing a "JVM Command line options" in the beanstalk UI.

Comment: are you using the Java SE container type @novon? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html

Comment: Yep thats what I selected.

Comment: Sorry -- this used to be an option -- it still appears in my older applications. I just spun up a new environment and it's no longer there. Looking to see what the new method is.

Comment: ah -- ok. you can set this with Software Configuration but try this key => val:

JAVA_OPTS: "-Dhttp.port=9000"

(replace 9000 with whatever value). LMK if this works and I'll update the answer to reflect the latest mechanism.

Comment: *snip* I spoke too soon, that seems to have worked as long as the application.ini file generated by sbt native packager is removed. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Will setup a test with activator

Comment: No need @dave-maple that does work, I needed to reupload my application package without the application.ini. I updated my previous comment.

Comment: Ok great. Can you accept if the answer looks right so others can find?

Comment: Running into this too, so on the SE container beanstalk image, JAVA_OPTS is some how automatically ingested by the JVM?